# phpmyadmin installed but not opening?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phpmyadmin is not working after I installed it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it)

I have ubuntu 11.04.

I installed lamp

So i automatically got things like mysql , php , apcahe which are needed for it.

It also shows that the phpmyadmin package is installed.

But when i go to this : http://localhost/phpmyadmin

It shows page not found ?

There is also a user named phpmyadmin there already.

How can i open to the phpmyadmin ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it/55282#55282 and see if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer to your question, but after the complication of setup and its slowness, I decided to use adminer: just one file, a lot of feature, more speed and no installation required: http://www.adminer.org . I suggest it to you.

Comment: DUDE ru serious ?
phpmyadmin much much better than this =.=

Comment: well, we have different opinion.. maybe try to read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

How did you install PHPMyAdmin? Did you use apt-get/the Ubuntu packages or did you grab the source from the PHPMA website?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin seems a little out of date, but that should help you get it working. If you installed it using the package manager, I've always found it easier just to do it from source downloaded from the PHPMA website. You just download, unzip it and copy it into your /var/www or wherever your Apache root is.

Comment: @bobbo-- I installed using apt-get