# phpmyadmin is not working after I installed it

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using **ubuntu-11.04**.

I followed these steps on this site:

- [Installing Apache2 With PHP5 And MySQL Support On Ubuntu | HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-11.04-lamp)

So far my apache2, php, and mysql are working fine except phpmyadmin... Whenever I run this:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

I get this error on my browser:

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> *Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80*

Comment: Have you restarted the apache server: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: Consider, checking answer provide by @sangharsh.

Comment: `sudo apt install lamp-server^` from first link in JohanSJA's answer. This installs any missing modules. Mine were: `libapache2-mod-php` and `libapache2-mod-php8.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Please read [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Phpmyadmin%20and%20mysql-admin) in Ubuntu wiki. You will need to configure your apache2.conf to make phpMyAdmin works.

```
gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line to the end of the file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I love you @JohanSJA

Comment: No need of manual configurations, apt-get ing is enough to run phpmyadmin

Comment: I finally got JohanSJA's instructions to work after I restarted the apache server using `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Also I moved the `Include` line to the **bottom** of the file as instructed.

Comment: I included apache.conf at the bottom and restarted apache server afterwards, still getting not found, how can I debug it ?

Comment: This worked for me, just remember to restart apache2

Comment: great but i dont know why manual conf needed..is this a bug?

Comment: This is correct answer .

Comment: @Tachyons apt-get ing wasn't enough. I had to Include the conf per the answer to get it working.

Comment: Muaaaah ... cyber kiss

Comment: I love you too @JohanSJA

Comment: Doesn't work. 
No protocol specified
(gksu:21503): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: I would prefer to do: sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
And then, restart apache2

Answer (score 28):

Tried various different ways.

Finally this, this from [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin), worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Worked on 15.10.

Comment: also worked on 16.04

Comment: This should be marked as the correct recommended way to achieve this

Comment: This is the correct way.

Comment: thanks. finally something that works. this should be the best answer.

Comment: Also worked on 18.04. Thanks

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer. Follows proper procedure.

Answer (score 6):

**Ubuntu 16.04**

After installing and setting up user and password in mysql and phpmyadmin execute following command

```
sudo apt install php-gettext
```

Worked for me...

**Edit1**
If you just need **apache, phPmyAdmin, and MySql** just to a Web Application Environment then I Suggest for exampp wich Install All three for you and then you are Ready to go Here is Link

[XAMPP Installers and Downloads | Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: This worked for me too. php-gettext was missing. I wonder, why none of the documentation mention about this module...

Answer (score 3):

Don't panic ! Just run the following code with root permission in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem, I fixed it by running
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

give new username and password

Answer (score 2):

You need to find where `phpmyadmin` is located, e.g. `locate phpmyadmin`,
some it will return the location, such as `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

Then you can symlink it like this: `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www`

Starting Ubuntu 14.04 and up, `/var/www` is no longer work instead `/var/www/html`. e.g, `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html`

Reference: [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Comment: If you are planning to host wordpress or another website in apache root i.e. `/var/www/html` then use `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`. That way you can access phpmyadmin using `http://yourdomain/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1):

finally this work for ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

now type  `localhost/phpmyadmin` in web browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sed -i '$ a\Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && sudo service apache2 restart && sudo apt-get install php-gettext`
```

Tested and works. Running that should solve it for anyone who wants a 1 liner.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above methods and they didn't work for me. Finally this one worked.

Open terminal and switch to super user using the command: `sudo su`

After installing phpmyadmin using instructions given in the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04), open `/etc/apache2/conf-available`.

You will find a file there named `phpmyadmin.conf`. Copy it to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`. Or simply use the command

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/conf-available /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
```

Restart apache2 (`sudo service apache2 restart`) and then open the link [localhost/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin) in a browser.

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same problem.

Firstly check if the directory called `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` exists. If it does, just move it to `/var/www/phpmyadmin` by executing this command:

```
mv /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Open your browser and open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`. Now it should work.

Comment: This will break the uninstaller, and will cause installation/upgrade issues.  You will need to symlink the directory.    `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin` should correctly symlink.