# How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

Recently I have install the PHP, Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, python in my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.3 LTS to use it as a LAMP server. The commands I used to install these are given below:

```
1: sudo passwd
2: su
3: apt-get install php5
4: apt-get install apache2
5: apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
6: apt-get install phpmyadmin
7: apt-get install python
8: apt-get install python-mysqldb
9: ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
10: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then everything works fine. The LAMP server runs great. Then i thought to upgrade the whole LAMP server I mean the PHP, Apahce, MySQL, phpMyAdmin etc. Then I searched in google and get some ppa which got the latest versions of these softwares. Then I added those ppa. The ppa links:

```
1. https://launchpad.net/~tuxpoldo/+archive/phpmyadmin
2. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/mysql-5.6
3. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2
4. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5
```

Then is used these ppa and firstly upgraded the phpmyadmin then MySQL server then Apache and then PHP.
After upgradation of phpmyadmin and mysql server the whole LAMP server runs well with the updated mysql server and phpmyadmin. But after the upgradation of Apache and PHP the phpmyadmin is not showing up. When I try:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin
```

it says "Not Found".

How can I sove this problem with the phpmyadmin?? Please help me as fast as you can. I am in great trouble for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider http://askubuntu.com/q/55280/192102

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Create a link in `/var/www` like this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/`

*Note: since 14.04 you may want to use `/var/www/html/` instead of `/var/www/`*

If that's not working for you, you need to include PHPMyAdmin inside apache configuration.

Open `apache.conf` using your favorite editor, mine is `vim` :)

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Then add the following line:

`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

**For Ubuntu 15.04 and 16.04**

- `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`
- `sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf`
- `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: After this I needed to restart the apache server.

Comment: Bypassed the first recommendation and went straight for the Include. Worked like a charm. Thanks @Achu

Comment: `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` followed by `sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf` and `sudo service apache2 reload` is the correct way with 15.04.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. I didnt need to make the sofltlink to /var/www

Comment: @Henry'sCat I think you should put your comment as an answer! Thank you.

Comment: 1000 thanks from me :* love you. Perfect answer!

Comment: Worked in mint-os 17.3 I used sudo this  `ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/`

Comment: Instructions for 15.04 worked for 16.04 as well. Actually, only these instructions seemed to work.

Comment: linking in `/var/www/html/` did the trick for me

Comment: Thank you, I always struggled on this after fresh Raspbian install. I bookmarked for post for later use

Comment: over the years... I found this the golden answer that I wouldnt know what to do or how to behave without..

a 1,000,000 Thank you for this I wish it was documented out somewhere that is as easy to find as this..

Thank you !

Comment: @ItachiSama You welcome a million :-D

Comment: @titusfx: Re your edit suggestions: this is Ask *Ubuntu*, so we're not looking for answers with deviating solutions for other Linux distributions and consider them “noise”.

Comment: Thanks a lot only adding Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf for me works

Answer (score 29):

Usually this is an issue after a vanilla install in **16.04**, **18.04** and **20.04** (**Focal Fossa**) and higher too.

To fix it:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: this is a much better solution than the answer that includes it into the main `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, since you can now `a2enconf` and `a2disconf` easily

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your apache doesn't load the configuration of the phpmyadmin part.

The link you made from `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` may not be valid anymore after the update. Make this link again, but notice the names may be different. After that, restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

you can also `install` this by `manual process`.

just download file to your `web root` folder.(/var/www/phpmyadmin)

for more [Click Here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install)
Download from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative way to do it:

1. Add to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` this "`Include conf.d/*.conf`" if it is not already there.
2. Next execute those two commands:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
   ```

It should be working.

**NOTE:** Depends on which Linux flavour you are using. If its Redhat or Amazon Linux, apache2 should be named httpd and path would be /etc/httpd, in Debian-based Linux like Ubuntu, folder name is apache2.