# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed php, mysql, phpmyadmin on my Ubuntu 12.04 localhost in the following steps:

I try these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

than after i faced phpmyadmin not found error and fixed using the following answer

[How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache)

After applying that fix I got another error message:

```
Forbidden  You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Change the permission with `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/`
and `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It solved :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the permission with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/  
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should check `/etc/apache2` and find the below lines:

   ```
   <Directory /usr/share>
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. the apache2 config should have this line:

   ```
   Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
   ```
3. Be you you phpadmin config look like this:

   ```
   Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

   <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
       Options FollowSymLinks
       DirectoryIndex index.php

       <IfModule mod_php5.c>
           AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

           php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
           php_flag track_vars On
           php_flag register_globals Off
           php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
           php_value include_path .
           php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
           php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/
      </IfModule>
   </Directory>

   <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
       <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
           AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
       </IfModule>
       Require valid-user
   </Directory>

   <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from All
   </Directory>

   <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from All
   </Directory>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me, was to uncomment the following lines:

```
<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue when I installed PHPMyAdmin in Ubuntu OS 16.04. I fixed the issue by adding the line [Require all granted] in the Directory section.

Example:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in centos
removing unnecessary backup files of configuration

[root@Stats-Server-1 etc]# cd httpd/

[root@Stats-Server-1 httpd]# ls
conf  conf.d  conf.modules.d  logs  modules  run

[root@Stats-Server-1 httpd]# sudo nano conf.d

[root@Stats-Server-1 httpd]# cd conf.d

[root@Stats-Server-1 conf.d]# ls

autoindex.conf  phpMyAdminbk.conf  phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave  userdir.conf
php.conf        phpMyAdmin.conf    README                   welcome.conf

[root@Stats-Server-1 conf.d]# rm -rf phpMyAdminbk.conf

[root@Stats-Server-1 conf.d]# rm -rf phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave

[root@Stats-Server-1 conf.d]# sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

Comment: none of these commands have anything whatsoever to do with permissions that I can see.