# after setup ssl phpmyadmin not working

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin, ssl, lighttpd

aim using amazon Linux   before setup  ssl

`ip/phpmyadmin` its working    i am using ssl for lets-encrypt  sudo `certbot --apache`  use this command and add ssl for my all web sites   now   when i type  `https://ip/phpmyadmin`   i got this error

> Your connection is not secure

so i click visit unsafe    then i got this error

> Not Found The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

and my os is cent os how can i fix this?

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Cent OS is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)  - Please ask on a Cent OS forum, or SE's Unix & Linux Q&A site...

Comment: i know but i post here if some know how to fix they will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo yum install epel-release

sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

then  try ip/phpmyadmin

if you got this error

> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.   [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/631580/852920) is the answer how to solve this