# Blank page when trying to reach phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I try to setup phpmyadmin to use mysql on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. But when I go on "localhost/phpmyadmin" I only see a blank page. I've tried some things like to include the conf, but it didnt change anything ([How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache)).

My goal is to use owncloud. So I created a user root and a user owncloud with the passwords. I specified the the user root as the phpmyadmin user with the pasword and

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

went well. But phpmyadmin doen't load.
What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**
Some packets were missing for php 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 16.04 Ubuntu desktop.
First configure `phpmyadmin` with apache2, append the following at the last line of the `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file:

```
#Include phpmyadmin: 
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Also make sure that the `libapache2-mod-php` module has been installed. If not, then install the module:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Then, after installing the following package, my issue was solved:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `gettext` installation command is now `sudo apt-get install php-php-gettext`.

Answer (score 0):

If there in no wrong in installation
TRY: Clear localhost cache and reload.