# PhpMyAdmin - 404 Page not found - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I've recently setup a Gameserver (that requires a MySQL, as well as a bunch of time to fool with it) and i REALLY didn't want to do this through a terminal.

Well, The answer was obvious Install phpMyAdmin. Or, perhaps not.
This is a clean install, One of the first things i did was to firstly:
1) Install Apache2
2) Install mysql-server
3) Install needed PHP components listed for PHPMyAdmin.
4) Install PhpMyAdmin.
5) Get hit by a brickwall, called PhpMyAdmin.

It appears to have installed correctly, I've tested Apache with both its own index.html as well as a .php, it can find them, no issues here.

Attempt A)
   I have tried creating a link with:
   " sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html "
Result = No Luck.

Attempt B)
   Inserting the line: " Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf "
   into "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"
Result = No Luck.

Attempt C)
   Restart server
Result = No Luck.

Attempt D)
  Check that MySQL is working (Incase for some odd reason that was it.)
  Status = it's working.
Result = No Luck.

Attempt E)
   When in doubt, Re-configure PhpMyAdmin?
Result = No Luck.

Attempt F)
   When in doubt, Reinstall PhpMyAdmin?
Result = No Luck.

Attempt G)
   "Go to sleep after banging my head against a wall for 17 hours."
Result = Headache.

Attempt H)
  Finally, Ask others that hopefully know a thing or two more then me.
Result = We shall see.

Regards, Tau.

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial for installing?  If so, a link would be helpful.

Comment: I just looked this up: How To Install and Secure phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16.04.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: can you please provide the the output of your apache error log? This might clear things up a bit. Without any log files or other information it's just plain guessing.

Comment: This worked for me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache

Comment: Alrighty, As for the Apache2 logs, I hope this is what you meant:
[link](http://pastebin.com/LGHvxFYY)
As for the "tutorial" i followed for installing:
Firstly: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) After that, When it didn't work, I removed both the MySQL server and Phpmyadmin and attempted another. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cINIskWrng)

Comment: One more thing, I'm not sure if this is just my browser caching Favicons but i am able to see the PhpMyAdmin Favicon.
(However it might be from an attempt on CentOS) Same ip.