# phpmyadmin is not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I installed `apache2`, `php7.0`, `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` and followed all instruction related to it. But `phpmyadmin` is not working

I tried all solutions here: [How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache)

Here is my `phpmyadmin`:

[image: here is my phpmyadmin]

Comment: Have you installed `libapache2-mod-php7.0`?

Comment: @Arun i just installed right now, and its working. Thank u so much. you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You should install `libapache2-mod-php7.0`

`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`