# I get a 500 error when going to /phpmyadmin in my browser after LAMP install

Tags: server, apache2, 20.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm testing `phpmyadmin` after installing `lamp-server` on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

First I installed lamp-server, then phpmyadmin

I made sure to select apache2 during the installation and I used `dbconfig-common`

(I didn't need to link phpmyadmin to apache2 thanks to dbconfig-common)

Finally, I restarted apache2

Then I went to browser, typed my server's IP address and I got the index.html page. But when I try to go /phpmyadmin I get a 500 error

P.S. I have also tried some of the suggestions from the best answer on this thread [How to solve the phpmyadmin not found issue after upgrading php and apache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache), namely, adding a symlink to phpmyadmin on /var/www/html/

Comment: Error 500 is Internal Server Error, which means your browser knows that there is `/phpmyadmin`, but can't open it because probably of server misconfiguration. Try running `apachectl configtest`, it will show you if there are Syntax Errors.