# Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, then I installed `lamp-server` and placed my webpages in `/var/www` directory, but when I opened localhost in the browser there was nothing.
I think that happened because Zend updated Apache.

Whatever the reason may be, I want to know where to keep my php files so that I can access them from my browser.

Comment: Although not an answer to the OP's question, the following answer may help some visitors who stumble onto this question while trying to fix a related problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/525120/1183

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The apache2 version that was published when the Ubuntu 14.04 release was made is 2.4.7 and starting with this version it seems that, for security reasons, the new root directory for the server is:

```
/var/www/html
```

So, from now on, this is where you must place the files for your (local) website. You should not have this problem again with the future updates.

---

Anyway, if you want to change this directory with another one, you have to modify (as root) the following line from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file (`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/another/directory
```

After this, for the new changes to take effect, you have to restart the apache server using the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried searching for the reasoning behind this move. If anyone is interested I found [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372) in Debian which explains it.

Comment: I'm getting forbidden error after this change.

Comment: @Darshana Default configuration in apache2.4 doesn't allow apache to access anything outside `/var/www/html`. Putting your site anywhere other than in that directory (or its sub-directories), will give you a 403 error. You need to add a [`<Directory /path/to/your/site>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) to your VHost configs with a [`require` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) in it.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Same here.. Its now gives me Error 403 forbidden! How should I solve it(In simpler, noober way PLEASE)

Comment: But why is in `apache2.conf` only the directive `<Directory /var/www/>` instead of `<Directory /var/www/html>`?

Answer (score 27):

Instead of modifying `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` back to the old version, I prefer keeping default package files unmodified.

A reason for this is that so it wouldn't break during the next upgrade again which might reset the `000-default.conf` file.
Besides, such modifications are not done just to annoy us, the modification was done for a good reason, as this [bug report in Debian explains](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372).

> Our webservers [sic] set the default document root to /var/www, whereas
>   site-local administrators tend to use /var/www/example.com. This has
>   security implications if visitors access the default document root,
>   bypassing the /supposed/ document root of example.com. That's
>   problematic if sensitive data is placeѕ outside the supposed
>   document root (e.g. consider a hypothetical
>   /var/www/example-com-db.conf configuration file).

A better solution would be to move the sites files from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html/`.

```bash
# 1. move all files excluding the `html` directory
sudo mv /var/www/[!html]* /var/www/html
# 2. Move the hidden files as well which are skipped in previous command
sudo mv /var/www/.[!.]?* /var/www/html/
```

Also, another possible solution is to create another Virtual Host and disable the default one with the command `sudo a2dissite 000-default`