# Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}

Tags: apache2, lamp

hi every body after clean install of ubuntu 16.04 
and tasksel lamp apache2 got this error :

```
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.114578 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.114623 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.114641 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.114645 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.114657 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Jul 18 22:42:00.133748 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4654] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Comment: OP, please review the answers below.  I recommend the one by @EnterUserNameHere.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That looks like you tried to start Apache by running something like

```
apache2
```

That doesn't work. Use

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

instead.

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this once and this worked for me:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars 
apache2 -V
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I haven't had the problem since.

Comment: considering lines like `export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX` are in that envvars file that makes total sense :)  If not one could do a `grep` for that var string if your apache config is different.

Comment: apache2 -V gave me error on miss configured vhost. Everything work well after disabled that vhost by using `a2dissite site.local` .

Answer (score 10):

The correct answer is quite simple yet not obvious.

The `apache2` service in Ubuntu/Debian uses the environment file `/etc/apache2/envvars` during its startup via `apache2ctl restart` or `service apache2 restart`.

In order to successfully show `apache2 -V` details just source the apache2 environment file:

```
# source /etc/apache2/envvars
# apache2 -V
```

There should not be any syntax error with the apache2.conf, since the environment variables shown in line 74 are automatically sourced by apache2 during its startup.