# Apache won't start after ubuntu 17.10 update

Tags: apache2

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm working with Apache developing websites locally.

Until today it worked fine but after updating Ubuntu via software and update, Apache is not working. I try to start the service but it wont start.
Beside this, when typing Apache2 on terminal, I get the follow line:

```
[Thu Nov 16 10:45:21.428052 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3509] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Read the error message. It tells you exactly what it thinks the problem is.

Comment: How did you start apache ? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/800214/invalid-mutex-directory-in-argument-fileapache-lock-dir and update your question of neither of those solve your problem (especially changing from /var/www to /var/www/html) . We need to know how you are starting apache (post the command you ran) as well as the syntax of line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Maybe you find this solution source /etc/apache2/envvars check your settings apachectl -S, apachectl -V