# Ubuntu 14.04 gedit error cannot open display

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, gedit

I'm trying to fix an apache2 error (see... [Why is my Apache not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04) to understand the error) but to do that I have to use gedit, now after installing gedit and using the command (shown in the link) `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and I get this error...
`Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`
Even if I try `gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` it gives me the same message (including when I type in `gksudo nano`). What's the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use gedit. Since you are on a server system, likely with only a terminal console available, you will need to either use X11 forwarding with ssh, or a terminal based editor.

To edit the file under sudo, just use `sudo nano` rather than `gksudo`. If you wish to forward your display, you can use `ssh -X` and then `gksudo` and gedit will work, but be somewhat slow, depending on your connection to the server.

Comment: it still gives me the same error message

Comment: another problem is that with the "edit" command it says that I can't get access ot the file