# apache timeout?

Tags: server, apache2

I have a dedicated server with apache2.
recently apache have started to die when the site is not being used.

example yesterday 8am i was doing some programming on the site everything worked fine.
today 10 am when i tried to log in it gives me the message `"server something.com was to slow to load"`

now once i use service apache2 restart it works fine again!
i'm pretty new to this so can anyone tell me what to look for?

also i tried to check the version of apache2 installed and instead i got the following message:

```
    [Thu May 05 12:14:26.037129 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.037154 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.037162 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.037179 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.037186 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.043258 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.043438 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.043540 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu May 05 12:14:26.043546 2016] [core:warn] [pid 19057] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

errorlog:

```
    [Thu May 05 12:27:24.550119 2016] [:error] [pid 19189] [client 5.154.190.132:47417] PHP  12. WP_Http_Streams->request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:433
[Thu May 05 12:27:24.550222 2016] [:error] [pid 19189] [client 5.154.190.132:47417] PHP  13. stream_socket_client() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php:150
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.156910 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://www.slscxhz66.com:80 (Connection timed out) in /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.157231 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP Stack trace:
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.157549 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php:0
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.157871 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   2. wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php:84
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.158041 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   3. IXR_Server->IXR_Server() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:197
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.158209 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   4. IXR_Server->__construct() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:440
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.158586 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   5. IXR_Server->serve() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:432
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.158964 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   6. IXR_Server->call() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:470
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.159293 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   7. wp_xmlrpc_server->pingback_ping() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:520
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.159487 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   8. wp_safe_remote_get() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:6306
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.159746 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP   9. WP_Http->get() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/http.php:70
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.159921 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP  10. WP_Http->request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:496
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.160012 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP  11. WP_Http->_dispatch_request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:342
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.160064 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP  12. WP_Http_Streams->request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:433
[Thu May 05 12:28:01.160112 2016] [:error] [pid 19196] [client 5.154.190.132:52254] PHP  13. stream_socket_client() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php:150
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.016210 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://www.slscxhz66.com:80 (Connection timed out) in /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.016521 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP Stack trace:
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.016791 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php:0
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017062 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   2. wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/xmlrpc.php:84
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017203 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   3. IXR_Server->IXR_Server() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:197
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017284 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   4. IXR_Server->__construct() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:440
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017640 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   5. IXR_Server->serve() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:432
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017734 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   6. IXR_Server->call() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:470
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017791 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   7. wp_xmlrpc_server->pingback_ping() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php:520
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017845 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   8. wp_safe_remote_get() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:6306
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017899 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP   9. WP_Http->get() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/http.php:70
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.017954 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP  10. WP_Http->request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:496
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.018007 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP  11. WP_Http->_dispatch_request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:342
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.018060 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP  12. WP_Http_Streams->request() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php:433
[Thu May 05 12:28:12.018143 2016] [:error] [pid 19188] [client 5.154.190.132:41993] PHP  13. stream_socket_client() /var/www/somesite.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php:150
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

what is your ubuntu version ?

If it 14.04-16.04 then check the:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

if you only show  = `/var/www`
then changed it to = `/var/www/html`

And restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: the document root is set right. and i've disabled the 000-default.conf and my my site.com.conf

Comment: and i'm not running ubuntu, i'm running the latest version of debian

Comment: This site is only for Ubuntu. I am flagging your question for removal.