# Apache not working (showing empty folders or 404)

Tags: apache2

I have updated Ubuntu to 14.04 and apache stops working.

I have reinstalled apache and all dependencies with no success.

When I enter localhost I see apache indexing the www/ folder but it is empty (although I have several files and folders). When I type in a folder I know it exists, I get a 404.

This is the error.log output:

```
juan@juan-TE5:/var$ tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Apr 21 14:46:48.899984 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21861] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 21 14:46:48.900108 2014] [core:notice] [pid 21861] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Apr 21 14:46:50.326343 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21861] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Apr 21 14:46:51.650818 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21937] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 21 14:46:51.650896 2014] [core:notice] [pid 21937] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

This happens when I type in apache2

```
juan@juan-TE5:/var$ apache2
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.933493 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.933700 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.933734 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.933749 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.933788 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.941240 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.941401 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Mon Apr 21 14:50:24.941419 2014] [core:warn] [pid 22112] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2 server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2-serve)