# What changed in apache2 from saucy to trusty for projects in /var/www

Tags: mount, permissions, apache2

I have some web roots in directories x,y,z, etc. in `/var/www/`, some of them (not `/var/www/`) are mounted with options `rw,bind,uid=301,gid=301` (301 is uid of user www-data and gid of group www-data). This worked very well in default `apache2` of `saucy`, but no longer with upgraded version in `trusty`. All permissions of all files and directories under `/var/www/` are owned by `www-data:www-data`. Changing all permissions to `777` (and restarting service) didn't help! I never changed any settings in `/etc/...` or somewhere.

EDIT: I'm getting 404 error when I request under `http://localhost:80/x` (error page suggests that apache is running: `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80`). No substring `error` or `fatal` in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. `netstat -tupln` shows that apache2 is running on port 80.

Any ideas?

EDIT 2:
Now the pages are also broken with lighttpd (don't have any CSS layout and edit links are not shown in mediawiki (this has been a behavior caused by malious redirection of apache, but can no longer be fixed by requesting the page under different hostnames)). Apache behaves as described before

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I meanwhile switched to lighttpd (which works after enabling configuration, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537888/lighttpd-403-forbidden-for-php-files)...

Comment: Is there really nothing to see in the error log? Can you check which file Apache is trying to open in the access log? Can you post your configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default directory of `apache2` seems to have changed from `/var/www/` to `/var/www/html/`. So one might (do one of)

- moving all content there to profit from the advantages of that change[1] (note that this might mess up mess up due to redirection issues)
- changing `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` back to `/var/www`

---

[1] see [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2-serve) (see comment of @Aditya and existing answer to the question)