# How to Enable Viewing Subdirectories in Apache2 Under WWW under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mysql, mariadb

Recently I did a "clean" install of Ubuntu 16.04. I also installed MariaDB, Apache2, and PHP 7.0.

Under Ubuntu 14.04 I could see the subdirectories under "`/var/www`". As a result of this upgrade I can no longer see them with "`localhost`" under "`/var/www`". However, "`localhost`" does show limited files.

For example, "`phpmyadmin`" shows up OK. And if I type just "`localhost`", I get the expected "`Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`" that is located in the "`html`" directory. Also if I type in "`http://localhost/index.php`", I get can the phpinfo() page.

However, if I type in: "`http://localhost/PHP_Intermediate/store/admin/admin.php`" I get the 404 error message: "`The requested URL /PHP_Intermediate/store/admin/admin.php was not found on this server.`"

The owner of all the files has been set to "`www-data`" with anyone temporarily having read/write/access privileges for testing.

How can subdirectory viewing (access) be enabled for "`var/www`"?

Comment: Please edit your question to use code blocks. It looks a lot nicer that way. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the error_log. You should have a more detailed information about what went wrong. You will also see what file is apache looking for and check if it really exists on disk.

Comment: No error messages are displayed. Nevertheless the error log implied a security issue. I turned off the "SSL Engine Switch". No effect. Still can't access my other web-pages under "www"

Comment: As a test, I moved one of the existing subdirectories into "var/www/html", and "localhost" displayed the files as expected. Need to do a bit more work to verify that the issue can be resolved in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have apparently located an answer. I noticed in `phpinfo()` that `DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/html`. I did an internet search to locate the file that string is located in. The file is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-conf`. See code below. "#" out the line with `html` in it and added a new line without `html`.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Solution found at this website: [Changing apache2 document root](http://julienrenaux.fr/2015/04/06/changing-apache2-document-root-in-ubuntu-14-x/)

In subsequent browsing, I ran across another post that speaks of this issue: [What changed in apache2 from saucy to trusty for projects in /var/www [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458581/what-changed-in-apache2-from-saucy-to-trusty-for-projects-in-var-www)