# localhost links have stopped working in XAMPP?

Tags: apache2, xampp

I have an XAMPP installation on Ubuntu 14.04 and its been working great ever since I installed it under 13.10, up until today. I was going to check something in my MySQL database via phpMyAdmin through the XAMPP page, which I normally access via `localhost`.

However, I went to do this today, and I just get a page that looks like this:

[image: localhost]

If I access phpMyAdmin via `localhost/phpmyadmin` it pulls up just fine.

However, none of my projects (all with index.html files in sub-folders) appear, or even the default index.html page. I added an `index.html` file to `/var/www/html` (I had read [this question regarding the new apache version in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2-serve)) and it displayed that page.

I also noticed that if I run the command `sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start` it says this:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-3...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.                 <----------!!!
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running. <----------!!!
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

which makes me think that the updated version of apache (installed with 14.04) is interfering with XAMPP somehow.

Funny thing is, if I FTP in (ProFTPD installed with XAMPP) I can see all of my files like normal.

I know that XAMPP stores its files in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, and all of my files are still there, but I can't access them.

I have googled all over the place for a fix, no one else seems to have run into this issue yet. Is there a fix for this, or is XAMPP rendered useless with 14.04?

**EDIT**:

I installed XAMPP via the installer.run file from the Apache Friends website and I'm running XAMPP 1.8.3-3, as you could see.

The version of Apache is the default installed one for Ubuntu 14.04 `2.4.7-1ubuntu4`. Configuration is default AFAIK, nothing changed around.

I would agree with the comments in saying that it looks like I have another instance of Apache installed, but I removed the LAMP bundle software I had previously installed before I installed XAMPP via the .run installer.

**EDIT**:

`apt-cache policy apache2` output, as suggested by Braiam:

```
apache2:
  Installed: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the repository version of apache2 installed. That's why when you use `/opt/lampp/xampp start` it tells you that there's already another instance.

Just remove that package and you should be all right. Here's how:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```