# php5, mysql, phpmyadmin not working in ubuntu14.04

Tags: mysql, php

I have already installed lampserver in ubuntu 14.04.
when i try to run http://'127.0.0.1', it shows it works. but it does not work when i try to run http://'127.0.0.1'/test.php. I have already created the test.php file in var/www/ . I cannnot figure out what is wrong with it. I have already installed php5 and mysql but it does not work.

Comment: Do you get an error message on screen ? what error message do you get in the apache error log (tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2-serve

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your php file in:

```
/var/www/html
```