# Apache 2.4.7 in 14.04.1 (server) htacces problem 500 error

Tags: server, apache2

After a do-release-upgrade Apache was updated from 2.2.22 to 2.4.7. This upgrade went wrong. First php5 didnt work, but this has been fixed.

Now I'm having problems when there are .htaccess files for a website. Then I get an the following error:

```
500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

When I look into the error log I get:

```
[core:alert] [pid 24367] [client 192.168.1.1:61274] /webhosting/mywebsite/.htaccess: ErrorDocument not allowed here
```

And I get similar error-messages for almost all the things you usually put in the `.htaccess` file for a website. When I move the things from the htaccess-file in between the `<directory></directory>` then the website works fine. So, in practice this means the `.htaccess` is useless.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Comment: Check if there is `AllowOverride none` in main configuration file for /webhosting/mywebsite directory, this disable .htaccess use.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response.

I couldn't find *AllowOverride none* in the configuration. However, your suggestion made me try to following by reversing the code from 'none' into 'all':

**< Directory "/webhosting/mywebsite/" >
AllowOverride all
< /Directory >**

And this works fine!

Kind regards,
Kevinx