# How to create php files in /var/www folder?

Tags: vim, vi, restricted

I am new to Ubuntu(Linux) and I am trying to create a php file in `/var/www`, file name `hello.php`. I am typing `vi hello.php` and then I write my code `<?php......?>`, however, when I am trying to save the file by `:wq`, I get an error and no file by the name of Hello.php is created..

Comment: Try using **vim** instead, unless you are completely unable to load/install any software. **`sudo apt-get install vim build-essential`**

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @david6 `vi` is a synonym of `vim` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

Open `/var/www/`

`cd /var/www/`

Create the file

`sudo touch hello.php`

Open the file

`sudo vi hello.php`

Enter write mode (we were in command mode initially) by pressing `a` (note that `vi` is case sensitive)

After that, press `Esc` (to change to command mode) and type `:wq`. Check if everything is fine with `cat hello.php`.

However, it's probably a better idea to use editors such as `vim` or `nano` as work with them is a lot simpler than that.

Comment: Go to the folder 
root$: cd /var/www/html

create file sudo touch hello.php

check your file in the list by typing "ls"
root$:/var/www/html$ ls

edit the file and save
root:/var/www/html$ sudo nano hello.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a more user-friendly text editor with many additional features.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vim
   ```

   vim is run from the terminal.
2. If you have installed Apache HTML Server (apache2), the right location to place your local website is `/var/www/html/`. That's where to keep your php files so that you can access them from your web browser. For more information see: [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2).

Comment: Isn't vim comes in the default install of Ubuntu,  and vi is just a sim-link to it?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, vim comes in the default installation of Ubuntu server, but vim doesn't come in the default installation of Ubuntu desktop. Source: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder

```
root$: cd /var/www/html
```

create file 
`sudo touch hello.php`

check your file in the list by typing "ls"

```
root$:/var/www/html$ ls
```

edit the file and save

```
root:/var/www/html$ sudo nano hello.php
```