# where to save your files of php in ubuntu to load on server?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, webserver, web-development

How to save our php files so that we can load on our server . I have installed apache2 , php, and mySql . also I don't know how to connect these 3 so that I can simply work on my text editor. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is integrated into apache upon installation and so, there is no need to worry. You can put php code into .php files into the web server. Foe example, instead of using `index.html`, you should use `index.php` so you can put php code into it. Here's a sample piece of code that can be used and easily understood -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Foo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
    echo "Hello World!";
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

For managing your mySQL database, you may use the package `phpmyadmin` from the official repositories.

---

For more information, refer to the following links -

1. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
2. [PHP 5 tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

---

For Another interpretation of the question, refer to [this question that was asked previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)