# install php in Linux

Tags: playonlinux

I am use VM VirtualBox to use Linux system because I wanna to install php on the Linux system I follow all steps to install apache2 , Mysql , php5 ... and then when put localhost in my browser this page what I get lit works 
but when I try to run any code by php the result does not appear in the browser. What is wrong.

I try to upload photo but I cant
https://www.dropbox.com/sc/gblwugj7ymdj8lq/AADPMze-5t_lr1zRYWCAGlpNa
 this link for my photo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Comment: Okay I will try

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct. Just put the php files in the relavent folder to get it working.

The apache server's root is at `/var/www/html`. Make sure your place the local website in that location to get it working. You can also change the root server directory and restart the server, if needed.

Comment: How I can make sure the php file in the relevent  folder to run code php

Comment: Consider reading the "Understanding the Folder Structure" part at  https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_a_LAMPP_server_for_PHP_development/Linux_desktop. That might help.

Comment: also I still facing the problem I cant run code php anyone can help me