# apache2,php and mysql - facing problem in editing the files and loading them in browser

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, webserver, phpmyadmin

friends, I have installed apache2 , php and mysql but now the problem is I don't know where to write the programs and put them back into the server folder so that I can access them back.My file i.e html and php file should be place in /var/www folder but when I try to create new document I'm not able to create it it's showing access denied. Please help me....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed access to a file, precede the command you are typing with `sudo`, this should prompt you for your password. The `sudo` command basically means "superuser do". So you have privileges of the root user when you use it. Example: `sudo vi index.html`.

Hope that sorts that part of the problem out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add your user to the group that owns `/var/www/`, usually `www-data`

Check the group of /var/www

```
ls -la /var/ | grep www
```

where the output will be something like

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 ago  1 16:10 www
```

on my output the second `www-data` position indicates the group is actually `www-data`

so now you have to add yourself to that group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data yourUserName
```

ensure that users belong to www-data can write to that dir

```
sudo chmod -R 0775 /var/www/
```

Logout and login again to refresh permissions. Now you should be able to write with your user on that under that dir.

Note : if the group is different from www-data, you should check which group is running apache and makes changes according to it

```
grep GROUP /etc/apache2/envvars
```

The output is something like this

export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

To change the ownership of /www/data use

sudo chown -R useOwner:groupOwner /var/www/