# Add entire php website to LAMP

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I have a php website that I would like to add to my localhost so I can do some testing but can't figure out how to add it correctly. The website has multiple directories built into it. If someone could lead me in the right direction that would be great. I have tried a couple of the tutorials online but nothing seems to be working right for me. `They all deal with setting it up with a single html file.`

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the entire website in /var/www/. This is the "webroot", or the place where all website files are stored.

Comment: If Ubuntu's version is 13.04 or newer, The DocumentRoot became `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www`. For more information, check this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2