# The Requested URL Not Found

Tags: networking, server, apache2, php, lamp

Edit: I've confirmed that my webserver's DocumentRoot is pointing to `var/www` where all of my CRM files are.

Just to get this out of the way: I have been thrown under the bus, they know I don't know Ubuntu at work but they need this issue fixed for a  new client.  So please, no lecturing.

Fast forward...

I have a client running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  They're running presumably LAMP, and a CRM called SuiteCRM; however, I can't access it.  Even from the machine it's on.

When I try to go it: http://localhost/suitecrm

I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /suitecrm was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

At first I thought maybe the LAMP services weren't started; however, I can go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

The files are in `var/www`... it has worked up until Friday.

Are there any suggestions you guys have for me to try?  I'm lost, and I've been at this for hours.

Edit #2:

My 000-default.conf file:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is `ProjectRoot` set to `/var/www/` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`? See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2

Comment: I don't see a projectroot... just a documentroot.  And it['s set to /var/www/

Comment: Can you find any entries in your Apache error log when this error occurs, which will be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or some similar location?  This might help explain where it is looking for the file.

Comment: @thomasrutter Only `[Sun Nov 13 18:40:12.601836 2016] [:error] [pid 29711] [client 127.0.0.1:48508] phpmyadmin: Failed to load /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php Check group www-data has read access and open_basedir restrictions., referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: This looks like a separate problem with phpmyadmin, but open_basedir restrictions may be causing all your problems.

Comment: @thomasrutter I know, I'm just showing that there's only entries for phpmyadmin.

Comment: @thomasrutter how do I deal with open_basedir?

Comment: On further consideration I think that a "not found" error is probably not caused by an open_basedir issue.  That is a PHP setting that can restrict software from opening certain files, but your error is occurring at the Apache server level, apparently not within the PHP.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but did you check the *exact* spelling of the directory that SuiteCRM is installed in? Ubuntu, like Linux and Unix systems in general, is case sensitive. So, for example, if SuiteCRM is installed in `/var/www/SuiteCRM`, it's not available under `http://localhost/suitecrm`, but should be under `http://localhost/SuiteCRM`.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck It's suitecrm, no capital letters.

Comment: Another wild guess, are you sure that the DocumentRoot is `/var/www/`and not `/var/www/html/`? Since Apache 2.4.x, the default is `/var/www/html`, in contrast to `/var/www` for earlier versions. `/var/www/html` is also the default in Ubuntu 16.04. If SuiteCRM is installed in `/var/www/suitecrm`, but Apache "translates" `http://localhost/suitecrm` to `/var/www/html/suitecrm`, it would explain the error messages. It wouldn't explain why it worked before, though. Are other files in `/var/www/` found, maybe a `/var/www/test.html` as `http://localhost/test.html`?

Comment: Also, did you or your colleagues do anything out of the ordinary directly before or on Friday? Any updates, any config changes or new websites on that server, anything?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Myh 000-default.conf is in second edit.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Nothing was done differently.

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Maybe there was some kind of config change somewhere, and it hasn't been applied yet. If this still doesn't solve your problem, I'm afraid we can't do that much more without actually poking around at the machine ourselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48443/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-henning-kockerbeck).