# Host a website on lamp server

Tags: server, lamp

I have downloaded an application and I have the database and php files, but I don't know how to use the files to create and make the website on localhost. I have apache2 server and Ubuntu 16.04. I have MySQL and php installed on my LAMP server. This is the website that I want to see on the browser:

http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/#step1

I am completely new to lamp development.

Comment: I'm not in your position but if I were I would google search for tutorials.

Comment: Are you following the tutorial you linked? Where exactly are you stuck? Are you just asking [Where to place my local website starting with the 2.4.7 version of apache2?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2)

Comment: I have created the database  and it reflects in phpmyadmin. But I cannot figure out how can I place the files in var/www or var/www/html or I exactly  and what is the entire process  to view the website in localhost.

Comment: I am trying to create the website in the link below. Please guide me through the steps so that  I can view the website in localhost/. This is what I want to create.      http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/#step1

Comment: Hi!    I tried to create a small html page and get it working in  a web browser. The web page opens in index.html  in the following link   file:///var/www/btnhd.com/public_html/index.html      but it cannot be viewed in the browser. I cant understand the reason. Please help me   thanks  Vicky