# How to get access to files in hostname/var/www/folder

Tags: apache2, php, html

How can i get access to files in hostname/var/www/folder?
I get an error saying not found - the requested URL /phpfiler(my created folder) was not found on this server?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to access the folder?

Comment: If you are using 14.04 or newer, you should put your folder in `/var/www/html` and not `/var/www`. https://askubuntu.com/q/448944/8698

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

Establish a [folder] at /var/www

Change the directory owner and group:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/[folder]
```

Allow the group to write to the directory with appropriate permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Add yourself to the www-data group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [user]
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried it but, i do not get access from the localhost/var/www/filer website. What could be the error here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding yourself to a system group as suggested here I would recommend to just set your file ownerships to

```
 sudo chown <yourUser>:www-data -R /var/www
```

On this way you can set different permissions for your user and www-data on any file (or again on everything within a certain folder using `-R` as before):

The permissions you can set are

- `w` write
- `r` read
- `x` execute (also needed to access folders)

A `+` grants the permission, a `-` revokes it.

=> So

- to set your users' permissions on a file e.g.

  ```
  sudo chmod u+wr /path/to/file
  ```
- to set www-data's permissions on a file e.g. only read permission

  ```
  sudo chmod g+r /path/to/file
  sudo chmod g-wx /path/to/file
  ```

The same methods also apply to folders so to allow the www-data group to write into a folder:

```
sudo chmod g+w /path/to/folder
```

and if you want also to be able to write to any file within that folder

```
sudo chmod g+w -R /path/to/folder
```

---

For accessing folders different from `/var/www/html` you'll have to add a redirection.

I'll quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076680/7111561) (they did it for something in `/home`)

> If you are using apache you'll have to create an alias that makes that images accesible via the web server.
>
> Here comes an example for apache2
>
> ```
>   Alias /img /home/path/to/images
>   <Directory "/home/path/to/images">
>      Order allow,deny
>      Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> ```
>
> Place this configuration snippet in the proper place of your apache installation e.g. end of httpd.conf or a separate file. Don't forget to restart your webserver.
>
> Now you should be able to access the images like:
>
> ```
> <img style="vertical-align:bottom" src="http://www.myserver.com/img/buy_button.png"border="0" />
> ```