# Ubuntu and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my VM Virtual Box, installing phpmyadmin in the process using the command

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I configured phpmyadmin with Apache2 and advanced options, and also set up a username and password.

I'm currently logged into my virtual box and have opened Ubuntu 14.04. I'm also logged into my Webmin 1.680 page using localhost:10000. However, when I attempt to open phpmyadmin in a new browser window, using the appropriate URL details, I receive a 404 error.

I've tried the various suggestions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/114221/how-can-i-start-phpmyadmin/114258#114258) ,but have not been able to correct the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly did you do in the 'I configured phpmyadmin with Apache2 and advanced options' step? An intresting question you can look at is http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2-serve

Comment: Voting to close this. OP "solved it" without any idea what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Not sure why it worked this time, but I tried

```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

again, and it worked.  I'm now able to access my phpmyadmin account.